# iPhone code browser?

Tags: iphone

I want to be able to read code on my iPhone in the bus every day. Ideally, I'd like to be able to download a package, extract it to a folder, put it on the iPhone, and be able to just browse through the code (folders & files and all). Don't need to be able to edit, just read.

Is there a good solution for this? If there is not, could it be a good first project to teach myself iPhone development? or would it be too big a chunk for a first bite? (right now I mainly just do python web app development)

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check out the [Airsharing](http://www.avatron.com/products/) app. When you run the app, it creates a server on your network (when sharing is enabled) and provides you an ip address you punch into a browser. You then upload files to the device via an ajax interface. Later on, you just open up the app and click the file you want to read and it displays on the screen. I've fiddled with it and it does preserve code highlighting.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I tried this this weekend and it works great. I did a click-by-click writeup on how to set it up, can be found here: http://teebes.com/2009/08/03/how-to-browse-files-offline-on-the-iphone/

Answer (score 1):

You might also check out the new MobileMe iDisk app that just got released today.  It looks like a slick way to share files between the iPhone and a Mac (and the cloud).  You need to be a MobileMe subscriber, though.